# Как сделать это? Не знаю за что браться

Tags: python

Миша сидел на занятиях математики в Высшей школе экономики и решал следующую задачу:
дано три целых числа (a=[1,5],b=[5,7],c = [1,2]) и нужно расставить между ними знаки + и × так, чтобы результат полученного арифметического выражения был нечётным (например, между числами 5, 7, 2, можно расставить
арифметические знаки следующим образом: 5×7+2 = 37). Миша срочно убегает в гости, от вас требуется написать программу решающую данную
задачу.

Какие условия поставить? или как можно перебирать эти числа? пытался сделать так

```
a = 1 
b = 5 
c = 1 
k=0
for i in range(8):
if (a * b + c) % 2 != 0:
    k += 1
elif a * b + c == 0:
    a = 5
elif (a * b + c) % 2 != 0:
    k += 1
elif a * b + c == 0:
    b = 7
elif (a * b + c) % 2 != 0:
    k += 1
elif (a * b + c) % 2 == 0:
    c = 2
print(k)
```

Что можно использовать, чтобы в if он проверил каждое число, то есть `1*5+1` потом `5*5+1` и также со знаками.

Answer (score 0):

среди чисел есть чётные и нечётные

1. все чётные можно сократить до одного чётного умножив их друг на друга
2. все нечётные можно сократить до одного нечётного умножив их друг на друга
3. сложить одно чётное и одно нечётное - получится нечётное

Пример:

```
1 4 97 216 332 3 91
```

чётные:

```
4 216 332
```

сокращаем

```
4 * 216 * 332
```

нечётные:

```
1 97 3 91
```

сокращаем

```
1 * 97 * 3 * 91
```

и итог:

```
4 * 216 * 332 + 1 * 97 * 3 * 91
```

Comment: знак можно использовать только один раз

Comment: и не очень понимаю как это использовать, while (19 + 1) % 2 != 0:

Comment: Похоже, что порядок чисел менять нельзя.

Comment: а можно ли как то записать в if или while переменную a как 1 и 5. то есть если он не удовлетворил условиям с 1 то он возьмет 5 и проверит еще раз

Comment: a = 1 5
b = 5 7
c = 1 2
k=0
if a * b + c != 0:
    k += 1
    if a * b + c == 0:
        a = 5  что то похожее но менее громоздкое

Comment: уточните задачу - дано только 3 числа? или давно произвольное кол-во чисел? можно ли менять порядок чисел? знаки не ограничены (только одно умножение к примеру)?

Comment: a=[1,5],b=[5,7],c = [1,2] вот эти числа. порядок менять нельзя, можно менять только знаки. знаков всего по одному, нельзя использовать два раза один и тот же знак

Comment: а что значит a=[1,5] - это массив чисел, так? и какое же число можно из него брать? если знаки не могут повторяться, то знаки вообще только 2 способами расставляются

Answer (score 0):

Если задача в следующем:

1. дана последовательность чисел
2. менять местами числа нельзя
3. расставить знаки между числами, чтобы получился нечётный результат

То код может выглядеть так (генерацию случайных чисел просто для отладки поставил):

```
import random

#nums = list(map(int, input("введите числа: ").split()))

nums = [random.randint(1, 20) for _ in range(10)]

# найти сначала последовательность чётных чисел
part1 = []
for value in nums:
    if value % 2 == 0:
        part1.append(value)
    else:
        break

# найти последовательность нечётных чисел
part2 = []
for value in nums[len(part1):]:
    if value % 2 == 1:
        part2.append(value)
    else:
        break

# найти последовательность оставшихся чисел:
part3 = nums[len(part1) + len(part2):]

# вывести комбинацию:
text1 = '' if len(part1) == 0 else ' * '.join(map(str, part1))
text2 = '' if len(part2) == 0 else ' * '.join(map(str, part2))
text3 = '' if len(part3) == 0 else ' * '.join(map(str, part3))

print(f"{text1} {'+' if len(text1) else '' } {text2} {'+' if len(text3) else ''} {text3}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так, например:

```
a_list = [1,5]
b_list = [5,7]
c_list = [1,2]
for a,b,c in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list):
    for s1,s2 in ['*+','+*']:
       expression = f'{a}{s1}{b}{s2}{c}'
       result = eval(expression)
       if result % 2:
           print(f'{expression} = {result} нечётное')
```

Вывод:

```
5*7+2 = 37 нечётное
5+7*2 = 19 нечётное
```

Знаю, что `eval` - это небезопасно, но что-то `ast.literal_eval` не хочет с умножением работать, а решения этой проблемы какие-то сложные все.